# Strange output when attempting to print from an array of pointers c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm attempting to create an array of pointers.

```
struct vertex
{
std::string id;
std::string name;
int networkID;
std::vector<adjVertex> friends;
bool visited;
};

struct hobbylist
{
std::string hobby;
std::vector<vertex*> list;
};

hobbylist * hobbies[HASHMAP_SIZE];
```

adding the user to the hobbies array:

```
int Graph::addUserToHobby(std::string hobby1, std::string id){
// initial key is based on the first 2 characters of the hobby name
int key = (hobby1[0] + hobby1[1]) % HASHMAP_SIZE;
cout << " initial hashmap key " << key << endl;
hobbylist *h = new hobbylist;
h->hobby = hobby1;
hobbies[key] = h;
}
```

my goal is to create an array of pointers with the hobbylist type, when attempting to print the contents of that array I end up with a very strange random symbol output:

GLIBC_2.2.5GLIBCXX_3.4.13GLIBCXX_3.4.14CXXABI_1.3GLIBCXX_3.4� P&y

I attempt to print it as so:

```
void Graph::displayHobbies(){
cout << "========================================\n";
cout << "DISPLAYING HOBBY INTERESTS =============" << endl;
for(auto const& value: hobbies)
{
    cout << value->hobby << ":" << endl;
}
}
```

I was wondering if I am printing incorrectly or if I am adding the hobby to the hobbies array incorrectly.

Changed Code:

```
hobbylist *h = new hobbylist;
h->hobby = hobby1;
if(hobbies[key] ==NULL){
h->list.push_back(user);
hobbies[key] = h;
}
else if (hobbies[key]!=NULL){
    h= hobbies[key];
    h->list.push_back(user);
}
```

Changed code is above and I am getting a seg fault at the last line in the else statement when running the function the first time and I am confused why the function would go to the else statement when the array should be empty and therefore hobbies[key] should be null the first time the function is run?

Comment: Initialize the pointers of array to `nullptr` (`hobbylist* hobbies[HASHMAP_SIZE] {}`), and check that before printing (`if (value) {std::cout << value->hobby << ":" << std::endl;}`).

Comment: Or even better, use array of `std::unique_ptr<hobbylist >` to avoid manual memory management.

Comment: Maybe `std::map<std::string, hobbylist>` (or `std::unordered_map`) would make more sense, since the hobbies are being keyed by name, which is what a `map` is good for.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions but unfortunately my class is very strict and I am unable to modify the header file in any way without losing lots of points. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have at least two bugs.

```
hobbylist *h = new hobbylist;
h->hobby = hobby1;
hobbies[key] = h;
```

`key` is your hash key. If `hobbies[key]` already has a pointer, this is going to leak memory.

```
for(auto const& value: hobbies)
{
    cout << value->hobby << ":" << endl;
}
```

This assumes that every slot in the `hobbies` hash array contains a pointer. This is unlikely. If a particular `value` in `hobbies` has never been initialized (none of the previously inserted `hobbies` mapped to that hash key), the pointer will be `NULL`, and `value->hobby` will attempt to dereference a `NULL` pointer, resulting in undefined behavior. That's your likely crash.

Comment: That seems to fall under the "memory leak" category, as described.

Comment: so i've changed it a little bit to: